# Create class with javassist and make it available

Tags: java, classloader, javassist

I want to do the following:

```
try {
    Class.forName("MyClass");
} catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
    ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
    CtClass cc = pool.makeClass("MyClass");
    Class.forName("MyClass");
}
```

I have tried it, but it doesn't seem to work always... It works in one context, but in the other the same code is crashing on the second "Class.forName("MyClass")"... Calling `cc.toClass()` always brings the correct class, and have tried `cc.writeFile()` but it makes no difference. Somehow, in some cases the second Class.forName finds the class, and in other cases it just breaks... Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that my code was creating the class on different classloaders depending where I was calling it from. I solved this by doing the following:

```
try {
    Class.forName("MyClass");
} catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
    ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
    CtClass cc = pool.makeClass("MyClass");
    cc.toClass(this.getClass().getClassLoader(), this.getClass().getProtectionDomain());
    Class.forName("MyClass");
}
```

Calling the `toClass` method with the proper Classloader did the trick... I was just unsure on how to control on what classloader the created class would become available, but the method with the classloader parameters allows exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
`try {
    Class.forName("MyClass");
} catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
try {
    ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
    CtClass cc = pool.makeClass("MyClass");
    Class.forName("MyClass");
catch(Exception e) {
}
}`
```

Check with this code, sometime jvm optimize the code and shuffle the statements , except in try block.

Comment: Well, the second try block is there, I just uploaded a "shortened" version to show the problem... What I noticed is that the cc.toClass() was not always using the same classloader (this is for unittesting).