# RJDBC and Class.forName Violation

Tags: java, r, javafx-2, javassist

I'm using R programming in Java using the package `rJava`.

Connecting with Database in R using `RJDBC` with the following code:

```
library(RJDBC) 
driverName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
clapath = "D:\\Test\\lib\\External DB\\ojdbc6.jar";
databaseName = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostName:portnumber:databasename";
userName = "username";
password = "password";

drv <- JDBC(driverName,clapath,identifier.quote="`")
dbUnloadDriver(drv)
```

And am dynamically load class using Java assit for call RScript. Following Code.

```
//1st Java Assis Code
String classFile4Decrypt = "D:\\Java\\pre\\Controller.class";

  InputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream(classFile4Decrypt);
  ClassPool classPoolObj = ClassPool.getDefault();
  CtClass ctClassObj = classPoolObj.makeClass(inputstream);
  ctClassObj.setName("ScriptMethodConfig_001");
  ctClassObj.toClass();
  inputstream.close();

  Class<?> scriptFileMethodClass =  Class.forName(ctClassObj.getName());//loaderObj.loadClass(ctClassObj.getName());
   Class[] argTypes = new Class[1];
   argTypes[0] = String.class;
   String methodName = "testOB";
   Object[] parameters = new Object[1];
   parameters[0] = "Jayaramu";

  Method scriptGenricMethod = scriptFileMethodClass.getMethod(methodName, argTypes);
  System.out.println("Method Name: "+scriptGenricMethod.getName());
  scriptGenricMethod.invoke(scriptFileMethodClass.newInstance(), parameters);

  ctClassObj.freeze();
  ctClassObj.defrost();
  ctClassObj.detach();

//2nd Java Assis Code

ClassPool classPoolObj123 = ClassPool.getDefault();
  classFile4Decrypt = "D:\\Java\\pre\\Controller.class";
  inputstream = new FileInputStream(classFile4Decrypt);
  CtClass ctClassObj123 = classPoolObj123.makeClass(inputstream);
  ctClassObj123.setName("ScriptMethodConfig_002");
  ctClassObj123.toClass();
  inputstream.close();
  System.out.println(ctClassObj123.getName());
  scriptFileMethodClass =  Class.forName(ctClassObj123.getName());
```

From controller.class i call the RScript file.
Error is - At 2nd Java assit code Class.forName("ScriptMethodConfig_002"). Throws class not found error. If I delete the R script its working fine. Why does this happen?? Is there any solution for this.

Comment: You mention it's working fine without the R code. What about the R code by itself?

Comment: Oh Am sorry. I tell that the problem in R Script.

Comment: Can you try to reduce the code to a part where it goes wrong, and remove code irrelevant for this question? Also, backup and repace the code in your R script by `print("Test to see if the problem occurs in the R script or the Java part")` to see where the problem lies

Comment: Without this all code  not easy to identify the error. Let i Explain. when I run the java code. The first java assist load the "Controller.class" file in JVM . and the controller.class file call the R script and connect to the database. the second Java assist code load the  "Controller.class" to JVM. class.forName("ScriptMethodConfig_002") throws the "class not found exception". If i delete R Script from line 7. The error not came.

Comment: I have little experience in Java, does your R script work if you run it without running the Java code?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Bas. But that's not match my requirement. I should call R script from Java

Comment: Yes, but at least you will see if it is the R script that's broken, or the java code. Hence why I suggested in my comment before to replace your R code by `print("Test to see if the problem occurs in the R script or the Java part")`. This way you can see if you are calling the R script correctly.

Comment: Ya I understand Bas thank you. I edit my R script code in my question part. I tested already using print()

Comment: I think the actual problem was. I can't load new class to JVM after call R script.

Comment: Finally I got the Solution. I replace ctClassObj.toClass() to  ctClassObj.toClass(this.getClass().getClassLoader(), this.getClass().getProtectionDomain());  and Replace ctClassObj123.toClass() to  ctClassObj123.toClass(this.getClass().getClassLoader(), this.getClass().getProtectionDomain());  I refer it from  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26606450/create-class-with-javassist-and-make-it-available]. Now its working cool.