# How to instantiate a class created at runtime with javassist?

Tags: java, reflection, javassist

I've just started to use javassist and I can't seem to figure out how to instantiate a class made at runtime.

The `makeNewClass()` method makes the `NewClass` class like that:

```
public bin.objects.base.NewClass {
    public int quantity = 5;
    private float weight = 30.25f;

    public float getWeight() { return weight; }
    public void setWeight(float weight) { this.weight = weight; }
    public float totalWeight() { return quantity * getWeight(); }
}
```

This method works just fine:

```
public void makeNewClass() throws NotFoundException, IOException, CannotCompileException {
        // ClassMaker maker holds the CtClass object and handles all the "making"
        ClassMaker maker = new ClassMaker("bin.objects.base.NewClass");

        maker.addField(CtClass.intType, "quantity", "5", Modifier.PUBLIC);
        maker.addField(CtClass.floatType, "weight", "30.25f", Modifier.PRIVATE);

        maker.addMethod(Modifier.PUBLIC, CtClass.floatType, "totalWeight", null, null, 
                "{ return quantity * getWeight(); }", null, MethodType.standard);
        maker.getCtClass().writeFile();
    }
```

Now the problem begins. This method is supposed to instantiate the `NewClass`, access its fields, and call its methods.

```
    public void testNewClass() 
            throws Throwable {
        CtClass ctclass =  ClassPool.getDefault().get("bin.objects.base.NewClass");
        
        Object testClass = ctclass.toClass(new Loader(), null);
        
        // Throws NoSuchFieldException
        Field q = testClass.getClass().getDeclaredField("quantity");
        int quantity = (int) q.get(testClass);

        Class[] cArg = new Class[1];
        cArg[0] = Float.class;

        // Throws NoSuchMethodException
        Method m = testClass.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getWeight", cArg);
        float weight = (float) m.invoke(testClass, null);

        // Throws NoSuchMethodException
        m = testClass.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("totalWeight", cArg);
        float totalWeight = (float) m.invoke(testClass, null);
        
        System.out.println("quantity = " + quantity +
                "weight = " + weight +
                "totalWeight = " + totalWeight);
    }
```

Now, I already figured out that `testClass` is actually initialized as an instance of `java.lang.Class`, not `bin.objects.base.NewClass`. So, obviously, it will not find the fields and methods of `NewClass`.

The question is: how do I solve that? I tried using the `java.lang.Class.cast()` method, but had no success.

Comment: the code seems to be half translated half or might be jumbling up with variable names. Could you fix that please.

Comment: Sure. I've missed a few names in translation. I think it's ok now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was finally able to find out what was the problem.

Aparently, it was a problem with the ClassLoader. I've found the answer [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26606450/create-class-with-javassist-and-make-it-available). To solve it, I just included this line:

```
Class newClasse = ctclass.toClass(this.getClass().getClassLoader(), 
    this.getClass().getProtectionDomain());
```

@nullpointer's answer also helped.

So, after some more changes, the `testNewClass()` method ended up like this:

```
public void testNewClass() 
            throws Throwable {
        CtClass ctclass =  ClassPool.getDefault().get("bin.objects.base.NewClass");
        Class newClass = ctclass.toClass(this.getClass().getClassLoader(), 
            this.getClass().getProtectionDomain());
        Object objNewClass  = newClass.newInstance();

        System.out.println("Accessing the field 'public int quantity'..."); 
        Field q = newClass.getDeclaredField("quantity");        
        int quantity = (int) q.get(objNewClass);
        System.out.println("quantity = " + quantity);

        System.out.println("\nAccessing the field 'private float weight' " +
            "through the method 'public float getWeight()'...");
        Method m = newClass.getDeclaredMethod("getWeight", null);
        float weight = (float) m.invoke(objNewClass, null);
        System.out.println("weight = " + weight);

        System.out.println("\nAccessing the method 'public float totalWeight()'...");
        m = newClass.getDeclaredMethod("totalWeight", null);
        float totalWeight = (float) m.invoke(objNewClass, null);        
        System.out.println("totalWeight = " + totalWeight);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using reflection to get your class object as :

```
Field q = Class.forName("bin.objetos.base.NovaClasse").getDeclaredField("quantity");
```

You can do the same for other fields as well.

Comment: Didn't work. It throws a `ClassNotFoundException`. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @BrunoNascimento Did you load the class via a class loader?

Comment: confused from question, try with `Class.forName("bin.objetos.base.NewClass")` once as well please

Comment: Still not. That's the StackTrace:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bin.objects.base.NewClass
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)`

Comment: @Vince I loaded using `Object testClass = ctclass.toClass(new Loader(), null);`. 
I also tried `loader.loadClass("bin.objects.base.NewClass");` with no success.